# Permission Contacts in Xamarin Forms iOS

Tags: xamarin

I met an error display when I tried to access user contact to fetch all contacts: The splash screen hide the permission dialog.
Did anyone meet this error before? 
Interface:

public interface IUserContactsService
{

```
    List<PhoneContactInfo> GetAllPhoneContacts(IEnumerable<int> filterIds = null);
}
```

UserContactService.cs:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(UserContactService))]
namespace Test.iOS
{
    public class PhoneContact
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public string Name { get => $"{FirstName} {LastName}"; }

}

public class UserContactService : IUserContactsService
{
    string phoneNumber(string number)
    {
        string callNumber = number;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < callNumber.Length)
        {
            if (callNumber[i] == ' ' || callNumber[i] == 160 || callNumber[i] == '-')
                callNumber = callNumber.Remove(i, 1);
            else
                i++;
        }
        return callNumber;
    }

    public List<PhoneContactInfo> GetAllPhoneContacts(IEnumerable<int> filterIds = null)
    {var keysTOFetch = new[] { CNContactKey.GivenName, CNContactKey.FamilyName, CNContactKey.EmailAddresses };
        NSError error;
        CNContact[] contactList;
        var ContainerId = new CNContactStore().DefaultContainerIdentifier;
        using (var predicate = CNContact.GetPredicateForContactsInContainer(ContainerId))

        using (var store = new CNContactStore())
        {
            contactList = store.GetUnifiedContacts(predicate, keysTOFetch, out error);
        }
        var contacts = new List<PhoneContactInfo>();

        foreach (var item in contactList)
        {
            if (null != item && null != item.EmailAddresses)
            {
                contacts.Add(new PhoneContactInfo
                {
                    contactName = item.GivenName,
                    contactNumber = item.PhoneNumbers.ToString()
                });
            }
        }
        return contacts;
    }
```

}

Comment: Did you add the permission in info.plist?

Comment: Yes, I did @LucasZhang-MSFT

Comment: Can you share your sample ?

Comment: I updated my question.@LucasZhang-MSFT

Comment: Can you provide the code in your info.plist?

Comment: thank you @LucasZhang-MSFT. I have already fixed this error yesterday. It because I don't check ABAddressBook.GetAuthorizationStatus() == ABAuthorizationStatus.Authorized before I get contacts, therefore it stucks in Splash Screen

Comment: You can post it as answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
public List<PhoneContactInfo> GetAllPhoneContacts (IEnumerable<int> filterIds = null)
{
     // if the app was not authorized then we need to ask permission
     if (ABAddressBook.GetAuthorizationStatus() == ABAuthorizationStatus.Authorized)
      {
          GetContacts();
      }
     else Console.WriteLine("Error");
}
```